# Распараллеливание стримов

Tags: java, потоки-данных, concurrency

Есть у меня самопальный класс BitVector с единственный полем

```
private boolean[] bits;
```

Есть в этом же классе небольшой метод, который делает конъюнкцию(логическое "и") для векторов:

```
public BitVector and(BitVector anotherVector) {

    if (this == anotherVector) return (BitVector) clone();

    if (size() != anotherVector.size())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incompatible sizes: size="+size()+", other.size()="+anotherVector.size());

    BitVector intersectionVector = new BitVector(size());
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
        if (get(i) & anotherVector.get(i))
            intersectionVector.set(i);
    }

    return intersectionVector;
}


public Object clone() {

    BitVector clone = null;
    try {
        clone = (BitVector) super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (this.bits != null) clone.bits = this.bits.clone();
    return clone;
}

public void set(int index){
    bits[index] = true;
}

public boolean get(int index){
    return bits[index];
}

public int size() {
    return this.bits.length;
}
```

Возможно ли с помощью стримов распараллелить единственный цикл внутри этого метода? Ориентировочные размеры для поля bits - 1 млн

Comment: Если вас устроил ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему нет?

```
IntStream.range(0, size())
         .parallel()
         .forEach(i -> {
             if(get(i) & anotherVector.get(i)){
                 intersectionVector.set(i);
             }
});
```

или так, но замеры показали что первый способ чуть быстрее

```
IntStream.range(0, size())
         .parallel()
         .filter(i -> get(i) & anotherVector.get(i))
         .forEach(i -> intersectionVector.set(i)
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, думал о таком подходе, вот только не знаю, будет ли это потокобезопасным?

Comment: Имеется ввиду случай, если другой поток будет изменять один из векторов? Я конечно не знаю вашей задачи, но если ваш `BitVector` будет неизменяемым, то проблем не должно возникнуть. Например метод `set` можно инкапсулировать.

Comment: ок, попробую.. спасибо

Comment: Можно eще parallel stream использовать, оно быстрее, но не рекомендуют. в моем случае оно пропускает некоторые элементы

Comment: у меня кейс проверки 29часов длился. я поделил на 2 части, каждую часть запускаю в разных потоках, а внутри потока вызываю parallelStream(). кейс ускорился до 19 минут. пока проблем не замечаю